# How do I repair this broken pipe?

Tags: plumbing, repair

[image]

We just bought a house and while digging in the yard using a pick axe, I broke a pipe. Per my research, I need to put a joint there. The broken part is right next to the joint, so not sure how can I fix this.

The pipe probably takes the rainwater. Since its summer I think I'm ok for a couple of months.

Comment: When you finish repairing it, put the first couple of inches of dirt on top of it, lay some fluorescent flagging tape along the trench, then finish burying it. The tape will provide a warning for you (and any future landscapers) before hitting the pipe in the future.

Comment: Have someone flush a toilet inside the house while you watch the pipe to ensure its not a sewar line. If it is, don't use any water until it is resolved or you will likely have a sewage backup!

Answer (score 9):

Looks like a piece of drain tile, hopefully not a sewer line!  What you will need to do is uncover a couple of feet of the line.  Cut the pipe back beyond the coupling, then put in a coupling, a short length of pipe to a second coupling.  So you will have two couplings with a short piece of pipe between them.

Comment: Note: a hacksaw is needed to cut the pipe.  You will also need PVC primer and glue if you don't have it.

Comment: This looks far too thin to be a sewer line, it is most likely a french drain or meant for rainwater drainage.

Comment: Good tips from Michael & Maple ++

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this kind of thing a few times. However fitting that extra piece of pipe and coupling is difficult to impossible. Once pipe is together with glue you cannot move it to install the next length. I find it easier to get a length of the same size pipe a bit longer than the break then cut it in half lengthwise, now prime the original and inside of new half section and glue it to cover the break.  - By the look of the inside this is a water pipe. A sewer or pipe to septic tank would look really filthy inside - and we can see it's white.